# Using Xamarin.Forms.Dependency just crashes on Android

Tags: xamarin.forms

I've created a library using Xamarin.Forms.Dependency to execute native code using a shared project.

On Windows 8.1 and UWP it executes the native code correctly, but on Android it always crashes.

Having added the following code to this shared class:

```
#if __ANDROID__
    public class LocalDevice : Java.Lang.Object, ILocalDevice
#else
    public class LocalDevice : ILocalDevice
#endif
```

and also registering it manually via

```
Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService.Register<HPE.Xamarin.Forms.Utils.ILocalDevice>();
```

I now have a new error (not longer a null reference), here I now have

**System.MissingMethodException: Default constructor not found for type HPE.Xamarin.Forms.Utils.ILocalDevice**

And still I do have this in my class:

```
#if __ANDROID__
    [Android.Runtime.Preserve]
#endif
    public LocalDevice() // Necessary for Xamarin DependencyService to work
    {
    }
```

So it's not finding the constructor anyway... I'm using the very latest and updated version of Xamarin on VS2015.

Anybody has hit this before?

Comment: Still it might be really helpful to include the error message and/or stack trace :)

Comment: Hi, added the stack trace :)

Comment: What is the code you use to invoke your dependency? And how did you declare your dependency? It seems like you have forgotten the assembly tag, like: `[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency (typeof (TextToSpeechImplementation))]` as seen on this [example](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/introduction/).

Comment: Hi Gerald, there is only 1 class with 1 property in a shared project, in there there is the conditional code, and that works well on other platforms, but on Android it crashes. The class has the assemby declaration (works on other platforms) so the interface registration is ok... this is driving me crazy :(

Comment: I had a similar issue in a PCL, when I added the name of the interface (`[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(NameOfInterface))]`) instead of the class (`[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(NameOfClass))]`. This was in a PCL though; your `#if` suggests you're using a Shared Library.

Comment: @S.L.Barth I do have the class name in the assembly attribute. This is driving me crazy :(